# python "unicodescape error" when i try to make acending numbers with string

Tags: python

i am coding in python and want to do something with bad apple
here is my code

```
import ctypes
import os
from tkinter import messagebox
top = Tk()
top.geometry("250x250")
def hello():
    while True:
        
        numb1 = 0000
        numb1 + 1
        ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(20, 0, "C:\Users\Bader\Desktop\bad apple\img\thumb" + numb1 , 0)

B1 = Button(top, text = "play Bad Apple", command = hello)
B1.place(x = 35,y = 50)

top.mainloop()
```

it gives me this error
Unicode error unicodescape codec cant decode bytes in position 2-3 : tunacted\UXXXXXXXXXXX
I want the number to ascend each time it updates
can you please help

Answer (score 0):

you are using a normal string as a path

replace this `"C:\Users\Bader\Desktop\bad apple\img\thumb"`

with 1. `r"C:\Users\Bader\Desktop\bad apple\img\thumb"`

or   2. `"C:/Users/Bader/Desktop/bad apple/img/thumb"`

or   3. `"C:\\Users\\Bader\\Desktop\\bad apple\\img\\thumb"`

Comment: thanks, but i want to add the .png string after the variable,  is there any way i can do that?

Comment: after which variable ?

Comment: the numb1 variable

Comment: `r"C:\Users\Bader\Desktop\bad apple\img\thumb"+str(numb1)`

Comment: i dont mean that something like 'r"C:\Users\Bader\Desktop\bad apple\img\thumb"+ numb1 + ".png"'

Comment: I forgot the .png part